# VIM syntax file for specman

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, specman

Where can I find an updated syntax file for specman?  There are a number of these on the web, but I want one with recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use VIM, but this is the one we have posted on our project's wiki:
http://www.specman-mode.com/specman-vim.html

I know a number of people on my team are happy with it.